# Why does div with content move down in inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs like so:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

When the divs are empty, this code works fine. All divs align along the same horizontal plane. But! When I put any content in 1 or 2 divs, the divs with the content move down about 90% of the height:

```
<div class="div1">X</div>
<div class="div2">Y</div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Divs 1 and 2 are now spaced down in comparison to the normally aligned div 3. The plot really thickens when I add content to the final div:

```
<div class="div1">X</div>
<div class="div2">Y</div>
<div class="div3">Z</div>
```

Now all three divs are properly aligned at page top again. Not sure what's happening here or the proper work around?

Answer (score 7):

This is happening because the default `vertical-align` for a inline block element is `baseline`*.

This image from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) helps to demonstrate the baseline of text:
[image: baseline demo]
As you can see, the baseline isn't how far down the text goes, it is the line that the text is aligned on. With `vertical-align:baseline`, the div with no content aligns with the baseline created by the `<div>`'s with content.

This image may help you visualize what's happening([or, you can play with the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odmwtmfa/)):

[image: baseline demo2]

To make all your `<div>`'s align, no matter the content, set `vertical-align:top;`:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

[This article also helps explain vertical-align some more](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

---

`*` *[W3 Specs](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)*