# Inline-block element not in line with another inline-block element that has a Block element inside

Tags: html, css

jsFiddle: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/dkjain/s7nz6jgf/1/)

In the above fiddle, 2 `<p>` elements are turned into inline block's and the latter contains an `<a>` tag that is turned into a block box using css. The problem is that first inline-block does not appear in line with the second one.

It appears in  Chrome & Firefox. Can anyone explain this behaviour.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<p id="p1">
 PINK is paragraph No.1
</p>

<p id="p2" class="myp2">
<a id ="run-fiddle" href="#">Para 1 </a>
 YELLOW is paragraph No.2.
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
  background-color:#eee; border:1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 10px auto;
 text-align:center;
 padding:0 50px;}

p { 
 width: 100px; height: 75px;
 background: pink; color: blue;
 padding:10px; 
 font-size:14px;
 display:inline-block;} 

p#p2{background: yellow; }

#wrapper .myp2 a{ border:1px solid black;
display:block; margin-bottom:10px }

#wrapper .myp2 a{ color:red; text-align:center;}
#p2 a{ color:white; text-align:left;}
#run-fiddle {color: pink; text-align:right}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because by default, an `inline-block` element is aligned to the baseline of the elements around it. [This excellent CSS Tricks article may help you understand it better](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/).

Use `vertical-align:top;` on the `p`:

```
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  background: pink;
  color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0vh1gvbf/)

Comment: Rather than a solution, I am trying to understand why this happens ?

Comment: @dkjain I also wrote an answer about this a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184954/why-does-div-with-content-move-down-in-inline-block/35185005#35185005

Comment: When I remove the content from `<p id="p1"></p>` then p2 shifts further down [http://jsfiddle.net/dkjain/s7nz6jgf/3/](Here) and if I remove content from `<p id="p1"></p>` as well as  `<p id="p2"></p>' then this is what I get  [http://jsfiddle.net/dkjain/s7nz6jgf/4/](Here). Could you plz further explain these.Thanks